# Python : What is the answer for 1.2 + 0.7?

Tags: python

I was playing with the python command line, and saw that when I type

```
1.2 + 0.6
```

I get 1.7999999999999998, but when I type

```
1.2 + 0.5
```

I get 1.7,
Moreover, 1.2 + 0.9 gives 2.1000000000000001.
Does anyone know what's happening in here?
I'm just curious...

Comment: that has something to do with the fact how floats are saved in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: It has to do with how floating point values are represented in binary. This is not something unique to Python, but it does get seen more there. The following is a good description of what is going on: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/.

Comment: Duplicate of oh-so-many questions, e.g. stackoverflow.com/questions/19433508/python-2-23-0-6-6000000000000005.